# what is the best approach to send report by Email?

Tags: sql-server-2012, reporting, enterprise-edition, powerbi-report-server

I've been requested to create some sql server reports ( create a report and send them by email ) for some poeple. I thought it would be like 2 or 3 but now that they know I can do it, every week I need to create 1 or 2 more reports.

I use SQL Agent and some steps to create a table, populate with the desired results, then I send it inside a xls file. Thats really not a problem, But I would like to know what can be better used for this task, since now I have more then 20 jobs on my SQL Agent. its all well organized and etc but still, I dont like to be looking at it. I already have a lot of DBA jobs and I dont want to mix things.

Is reporting services a viable way to do this? can I normally create a query, them send it to an excel file and send it by email without using c# or visual studio?

Answer (score 5):

Yes sure.. you can use the subscription and delivery of Reporting Services to send a report.

The available formats are:

- XML file with report data
- CSV (comma delimited)
- PDF
- MHTML (web archive)
- Microsoft Excel
- TIFF file
- Microsoft Word

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/subscriptions-and-delivery-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15))

For delivery via email look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/e-mail-delivery-in-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Reporting Services is the generally preferred way of doing this.  You *can* create the reports completely inside the web designer if you have an aversion to using Visual Studio, but really Visual Studio is the preferred method for creating reports.  There is no need for any programming knowledge to make this work, just SQL.

If cost is a concern, SQL Server Data Tools is free and has everything you need to create reports.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15